# Printing in the next page in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a printing module that prints all the data in a ListView. The problem is that it continues printing the data until it reaches the bottom of paper. That is why I added `e.Hasmorepage = true`, but when I try to preview it using the `PrintPreviewControl`, the number of pages keeps increasing forever.

[image: Infinite page]

It should be only 2 pages

Here's my code

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Material name", ReportFontL, Brushes.Black, 100, 220)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Price", ReportFontL, Brushes.Black, 500, 220)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantity", ReportFontL, Brushes.Black, 600, 220)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Total cost", ReportFontL, Brushes.Black, 700, 220)

    Dim space As Integer = 240
    For Each LV As ListViewItem In Mainform.ListViewMaterialUsed.Items
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LV.Text, ReportFont, Brushes.Black, 100, space)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LV.SubItems(2).Text, ReportFont, Brushes.Black, 500, space)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LV.SubItems(1).Text, ReportFont, Brushes.Black, 600, space)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(LV.SubItems(3).Text, ReportFont, Brushes.Black, 700, space)
        space += 16
        If (space > e.MarginBounds.Bottom) Then       'Print new page
            e.HasMorePages = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps i'm missing something, but where are you setting the generating previews text?

Comment: i have  "PrintPreviewControl1.Document = PrintDocument1" when my form load.

Comment: Your loop is not correct.  It is going to print the first row of listview items, start a new page and then print the first row, then start a new page *ad infinitum*.  You need to use a  `For n` loop so it can be resumed on each page

Comment: I already use For n but still the same. here's my new for loop. `For index As Integer = 0 To Mainform.ListViewMaterialUsed.Items.Count - 1`